# Why can't we assign two inferred variables as an anonymous class to each other?

Tags: java, java-10

[Java 10](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) allows to do an `anonymous class` with a `var` like:

```
var a1 = new Object(){};
var a2 = new Object(){};
```

But this assignment will throw an error:

```
a1 = a2;
```

> `jshell> a1 = a2;
>   |  Error:
>   |  incompatible types: $1 cannot be converted to $1
>   |  a1 = a2;
>   |       ^^`

Based on the error log, why can't Java 10 assign two inferred `var`s as an `anonymous class` to each other, but it can do the same for other types like `Long`, `String`, etc.?

Comment: Because they are **not** the same! An anonymous class is exactly that, an anonymous `class` that inherits from `Object` - one is `Object$1` and the other is `Object$2`. It's like asking why you cannot assign an `ArrayList` to a `HashSet`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider are they both `$1`?  from the error log: `$1 cannot be converted to $1`

Comment: It's more of a problem with the jshell error message it seems. `javac` uses `<anonymous Object> cannot be converted to <anonymous Object>` (not necessarily the _same_ `<anonymous Object>` though)

Comment: `$1 cannot be converted to $1` looks like bug. When we remove `a1 = a2;` assignment and compile such code we will get (as expected) two anonymous classes with `$1` and `$2` suffixes. So expected error message should look more like `$2 cannot be converted to $1`.

Comment: Because they are not the same type.  They are two different anonymous subtypes of `Object`, and neither is a subtype of the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each `new Object(){}` creates a new type (an anonymous class). These types have no subtype-supertype relation, so it is not possible to assign `a1` to `a2` and vice versa.

But when you have two `long` variables, both actually have the same type `long`, so they are mutually assignable.